# Formatting stored procedures created by psycopg2

Tags: sql, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I have little bit cosmetic problem with psycopg2 and stored procedures saving in python, but it is really annoying and I cant find any info regarding this on web.

So let me explain. The whole thing work as it should, procedure is saved correctly and when called it works, BUT, when I want to check it right inside postgres database by command ("/ef") it is whole body of function in one line and it is really hard to read it.

The other problem with that is, that when some error or notification is printed by given procedure, it says everytime "line 1", since whole function is in single line.

Is there any way how to tell psycopg2 that it should create new line? Like "\n" or "\r" or whatever else..

Example:

Python code is:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
import psycopg2.extensions

query = ("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something() RETURNS void AS $$"
         "DECLARE"
         "    something RECORD;"
         "    anything INTEGER;"
         "BEGIN"
         "    FOR something IN SELECT thing FROM table LOOP"
         "        something := something + anything;"
         "    END LOOP;"
         "    RETURN"
         "END"
         "$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;")

print "Connecting to DB.."
server_cx = psycopg2.connect(SERVER_DB_PATH)
server_cx.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
server_cu = server_cx.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
print "DB connection ok"

print "Inserting query"
server_cu.execute(query)
print "Query inserted! Exitting.."
```

But when I put

```
\ef do_something()
```

into postgresql, I get this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something() RETURNS void AS $$DECLARE    something RECORD;    anything INTEGER;BEGIN    FOR something IN SELECT thing FROM table LOOP        something := something + anything;    END LOOP;    RETURN;END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

instead of this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    something RECORD;
    anything INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR something IN SELECT thing FROM table LOOP
        something := something + anything;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It would really make my life easier and happier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your input string in Python has no newlines, so the procedure sent to PostgreSQL also has no newlines.

Observe:

```
>>> mystring = ("blah "
... "blah")
>>> mystring
'blah blah'
```

What you should be doing is using a raw triple-quoted multi-line string in Python:

```
>>> mystring = r"""
... blah
... blah
... """
>>> mystring
'\nblah\nblah\n'
>>> print mystring

blah
blah
```